# Passing C Struct to Go Function in CGO

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have need to use CGO code. In this code I have a C function which is calling a Go function. I want to pass a C struct to the Go function from this C function. For now I am trying very simple struct but it can be complex. So how can I accept the C struct in Go function, I mean what should be the Go function parameter. Also once accepted inside Go function, how will I convert that to a Go struct.

Any help is really very much appreciated. I am stuck for few days now.

Here is my sample code which I tried

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

__attribute__((weak))
void testCFunc()
{
    struct Person{
        int age;
        char name[100];
        };
    struct Person pers;
    pers.age = 21;
    strcpy(pers.name, "John Doe");
    goCallbackHandler(pers);
}
*/
import "C"

type Person struct {
    age    int
    name   string
}

//export goCallbackHandler
func goCallbackHandler(rq interface{}) {
    //Below is not working
    t1 := reflect.TypeOf(rq)
    k1 := t1.Kind()
    fmt.Println("Type of interface:", t1)
    fmt.Println("Kind of first interface:", k1)
}
```